# Is there a comma before "must"?

Tags: grammar, difference

1) The person born the farthest away must tell a story.

OR

The person born the farthest away, must tell a story.

---

2) All girls whose phone numbers are not in your contact list must add you.

OR

All girls, whose phone numbers are not in your contact list, must add you.

---

3) Everybody must stand up. The last to do so must dance.

OR

Everybody must stand up. The last to do so, must dance.

---

4) Carl, who writes really badly, must correct his writing.

OR

Carl who writes really badly must correct his writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples

> The person born the farthest away must tell a story.
>   Everybody must stand up. The last to do so must dance.

the comma is not necessary and would not change the meaning. For effect, it would change the cadence of how it's read.

However, in

> All girls, whose phone numbers are not in your contact list, must add you.
>   Carl, who writes really badly, must correct his writing.

the commas are useful since they offset an adjective clause, but are not necessary since the clauses can be considered essential to understanding.

Comment: I am struggling to find a natural cadence that includes the comma in the first example. I am a great believer in using commas for cadences, but in this case it trips me up reading the sentence.

Comment: I'm envisioning a pause for effect, as in "The person born the furthest away,... will be shot."

Comment: OK That works but the advice must be to omit the comma unless you particularly wish to indicate a cadence of that kind.